# AJAX in JS file does not route to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this JS function

```
function initAreaNames(data) {   

    var selectedItem = data.value;
    //var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    var ddlStates = $("#AreaName");
    var statesProgress = $("#areas-loading-progress");
    statesProgress.show();
   // alert("selectedItem " + selectedItem);
    $.ajax({
       cache: false,
       type: "GET",       
        url: '@(Url.Action("GetAllAreasByCategory" ,"Address"))',
        data: { "CategoryName": selectedItem },
        success: function (data) {              
            ddlStates.html('');
            $.each(data, function (id, option) {               
                ddlStates.append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));
            });
            statesProgress.hide();
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Failed to retrieve states. ' + thrownError + " " + ajaxOptions + " " + xhr + u);
            statesProgress.hide();
        }
    });
}
```

and for some reason, my `GetAllAreasByCategory` doesn't get called.

I have tried to use `alert` `success` and nothing, but when I used `alert` before the AJAX calli did get the alert I expected

I tested this code  on the .cshtml(rewrote the function as a `<script> ..</script>`) file and it worked properly

this is my `.cshtml` file

```
@model ErrorSelector.Models.AddressModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="JSFunctions.js"></script>

<div>

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName, new {style = "font-size:72px" } )
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryName, Model.AvailableCategories
                   , new { @onchange = "initAreaNames(this)", style = @"font-size:72px" })



</div>
<br />
```

Comment: Is that script in an external js file? (razor code is not parsed in external files)

Comment: what do you mean by external files?
it just .js file in my project

Comment: That is what I mean - its a separate `.js` file :) - `@Url.Action()` is razor code. It is not parsed in external files (look at the output of `console.log('@Url.Action("GetAllAreasByCategory" ,"Address")');` to understand. You need to use `@Url.Action()` in the `.cshtml` file and pass it to the method (typically as a `data-` attribute of the element you are handling)

Comment: i tried data_url = Url.Action("GetAllAreasByCategory", "Address") on cstml , and on JS  var url = $(this).data('url');  but alert("url " + url); says undfiend @StephenMuecke

Comment: Delete your `onchange` and use `$('#CategoryName').change(function() { var url = $(this).data('url'); var selectedItem = $(this).val(); ...... ` (and it needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryName, Model.AvailableCategories, new { data_url = "@Url.Action(....)" })`

Comment: can i call the JS on another file(not on the main .cstml)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167986/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-styx).